# Отсутствие "умного" автозаполнения в VSC для Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Коллеги, 101.

Прошу не судить строго, ибо всю жизнь юзал Pycharm.

Поставил VSC от Microsoft и столкнулся с банальнейшей проблемой: при вводе любой функции я не получаю пресловутых скобок. Т.е., вводя какой-нибудь input, мне нужно шифтить и ставить () руками.

Это безумная мелочь, но так раздражает, что просто кошмар. Подскажите, п-та, есть ли какое-нибудь расширение для устранения этого мельчайшего недочета столь крутой IDE?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/101?

Comment: VSC это редактор, а не IDE. Хотя с кучей плагинов оно становится IDE :)
У вас стоит это расширение https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python? Гуглил и выводило на него https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13413 ну и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63965163/

Comment: python -> edit in settings.json - >"python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true - помогло :) Спасибо Вам за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Меняем файл `settings.json`, устанавливая ключ "python.analysis.completeFunctionParens" в true:

```
"python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true
```

Либо, через UI:

1. Идем по меню File/Preferences/Settings:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Вводим "completeFunctionParens" для фильтрации настроек и ставим флажок:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]